# Mysql query modification

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have this query that works grate it return 1 line in results, but where the results found in more than 1 line i get : Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row.

How can i make return all the results even if there is in more than one row?

the code is :

```
select numbers 
from vista 
where id = (
    select b.id + 3 from (
      select t1.id, t1.numbers t1val, t2.numbers t2val, t3.numbers t3val 
      from vista t1 
      join vista t2 on t1.id = t2.id-1 
      join vista t3 on t1.id = t3.id-2 
      where t1.id = (select max(id) - 2 from vista)
    ) a
    join (
      select t1.id, t1.numbers t1val, t2.numbers t2val, t3.numbers t3val 
      from vista t1 
      join vista t2 on t1.id = t2.id-1 
      join vista t3 on t1.id = t3.id-2 
      where t1.id < (select max(id) - 2 from vista)
    ) b 
  on a.t1val = b.t1val 
  and a.t2val = b.t2val 
  and a.t3val = b.t3val 
  and a.id <> b.id
) 
order by id limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the beginning of the query to this:

```
select numbers 
from vista
where id in (
```

and the end to:

```
order by id;
```

The query will return the number following all matching groups.

[See this example.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48ae4/1)